# How to create an intercepting middleware for token requests?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to write some ASP.NET Core 2 middleware and need to get in on the identity token request so I can modify the response. These aren't standard OAuth claims nor do they act like them. Rather, there is an additional header I need to generate on the OAuth response. However, I'm getting token responses completely out of band from the normal request/response flow which means my middleware doesn't get the chance to fire even though it's first in the pipeline.

I've played with the `IServicesCollection` a bit and have even successfully inserted a service to be "first." However, the breakpoint I have set in my middleware's constructor doesn't even fire before I get the token response, and I don't see any of the facilities such as `HttpContext` from the `IServicesCollection`. Even fetching the `IStartupFilter` and calling a `Configure` early doesn't let my middleware intervene at all.

How do I create a middleware (or service) that gets to go first before all others?

I'm using IdentityServer4.

Edit: Some code...

I've tried both the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMyService(Configuration.GetMyServiceOptions());

    services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
        .AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<MyUser>>(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider);

    services.AddMvc();

    // after this next line, my token request gets a response
    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false);

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryResources(IdentityConfig.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfig.GetApiClients())
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfig.GetIdentityResources());
}
```

Where `AddMyService` has taken many forms trying to get the correct injection. The latest iteration of it before posting this was

```
public static void AddMyService(this IServiceCollection services, MyServiceOptions options)
{
    var startupFilter = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IStartupFilter>();

    startupFilter.Configure(builder => builder.UseMyMiddleware(options.ToMiddleware()));
}
```

Other services I've tried to mess with in the above is `IClaimsTransformation`, `ITransportFactory`, `IAuthenticationService`, and `IHttpContextFactory`.

..and..

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvrionment env)
{
    // this doesn't get a chance to capture the token request
    app.UseMyMiddleware(Configuration.GetMyMiddlewareOptions());

    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

With the above, I get a response to my token request in a console app before a breakpoint on app.UseMyMiddleware or within my middleware ever catches.

Comment: I think you may be getting confused between an injected service and a middleware service?

Comment: I was trying to illustrate that I've tried both and neither seem to get the results that I want.

Comment: Well without any code to show what you have done, there's not much we can do to help you out.

Comment: It's easy to create a middleware to intercept an incoming HTTP request, e.g. https://gist.github.com/ignas-sakalauskas/a549088af4e66d8ab72f32161a9697dc, however it might be a cleaner approach to look for a wayt to add custom claims to IS4.

Comment: So `UseMyMiddleware` is the "exciting" bit here, what does it contain? What does your middleware look like too?

Comment: As I mentioned, the extra header doesn't behave like oauth claims and can't be added there and the middleware never executes on the token request. On normal requests, sure, no problem, but not the token one

Comment: @DavidG It literally doesn't matter because none of my breakpoints ever catch. If they did and I got that far, I wouldn't be asking this question. The fundamental problem I'm having is that my code never fires in response to the token request. I get a token response way before the middleware gets involved.

Comment: The `UseMyMiddleware` function doesn't run?

Comment: Correct. If I go back and do a normal route for a controller it runs perfectly. This is not so with token requests.

Comment: Well, it will only run once, all it's there for is to add your middleware to the pipeline.

Comment: I get that. I'm saying that doesn't happen on a token request if I step through it with my debugger. It's like as soon as MVC authentication gets added, it takes over everything oauth related and the middleware pipeline never runs. I can set a breakpoint at app startup and block normal requests all day long but my token requests get served normally in spite of the breakpoints.

Comment: @Bigsby, did you ever figure this out? I too have a similar need and am looking at adding query parameters sent back to the client along with the standard query parameters. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Vasan, I ended up using OpenIddict: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core